# Can't connect to PostgreSQL with Rails and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 5 application using Postgres to a VPS via Capistrano. It keeps failing, though - giving me a `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'sys_user'`.

The relevant settings of my `database.yml` are:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

All these environment variables have been set in `/etc/environment` - this is definitely the case because it's picking up the `RDS_USERNAME` as `sys_user`. The password of the database is the same as the variable `RDS_PASSWORD`. The port, hostname etc. are all the same also.

I'm stumped. Please help.

Comment: I don't have a solution. Using the `dotenv` gem temporarily (with `.env.production` not checked into version control, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Postgres instance running? I'm guessing that you're trying to migrate an application from Elastic Beanstalk to a non-Amazon host. If that's the case, and your Postgres instance is **not** actually RDS, you might need to enable password authentication in your config file.

Documentation on Postgres configuration can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html); I suspect you might need to change `ident` to `md5`.

Comment: Actually, it's a fresh deploy of Postgres on the same VPS. I haven't been using Amazon at all. For the `RDS_HOST` variable, I tried both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` both of which work on my dev machine but not on the server.

Comment: Was the application initially developed for AWS? If not, it's very curious that the `RDS_` prefix was chosen - those are the **exact** environment variable names used for an Elastic Beanstalk application. Regardless, I still suspect that the problem is with the configuration of your Postgres instance; if it's not configured to accept password authentication, then you'd get that error message.

Comment: It wasn't - the `RDS_*`  prefixes were chosen out of familiarity with Amazon, though. See my comment on the question for the temporary fix I'm using.